# Package name is not updating on change - cannot upload to google play

Tags: android

I am trying to reupload my apk after renaming the package name. I followed the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) without issue. The problem comes up when I try to upload the new apk to google play. For some reason the package name comes up as the previous package name and stops me from uploading the apk with the conflicting package name. I am uploading this apk as a new app.

I searched for the old package name throughout my project and it only comes up in the R.java file within the comments.

Is there somewhere else I need to update the package name?

Answer (score 0):

Clean & rebuild the project. Also, reset the cache.

Review if the build.gradle project name is the same as the AndroidManifest.XML

Then try to upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the applicationId in my build.gradle file from the old package name to the new.